# Compare multiple server times to localtime

Tags: bash, shell, date, time, scripting

I am looking to compare x amount of server times to a control local time(current time at the running of the script) to check if any of the servers are out of sync with the current time. If the servers are more than a few seconds behind then throw and error message.

This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/sh

servers="server1.... server2...."
now="date +%s"
for server in $servers
do
  ssh -l root ${server} "date +%s"
  if [ $? -eq "$now" ] ; then
    echo $server - IN SYNC
  else
    echo $server - NOT IN SYNC 
  fi
done
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `$?`, try to redirect the output of date to a local tmp file. Then read the value and subtract it from `date` output on your local machine. If the difference is smaller then a certain value, throw the error. -- Also get the local date after ssh, it'll be closer to it then before setting up the connection.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but how about using NTP on the servers?

Comment: I'm open to whatever works the best really, once the script is created I can make alerts off of it to notify me when there's a sync problem

Comment: hint1: now=$(date +%s)

Comment: hint2: trem=$(ssh -l root ${server} "date +%s")

Comment: hint3: not compare equal times (something near than impossible of be true), but difference small than some threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

servers="server1.... server2...."
seconds="3"  # value for servers to differ (in seconds)
for server in $servers
do
    difference=$(echo $(ssh -l root ${server} "( date +%s )") "-" $(date +%s) | bc)
    if [[ ${difference#-} -le ${seconds} ]] ; then
        echo $server - IN SYNC
    else
        echo $server - NOT IN SYNC 
    fi
done
```

I've given the script in pseudo code-ish, along the same lines you've given yours (I have switched to `bash` though).

Comment: Assume ssh time is 1000 and local is 100: 1000-100 > -3 => ok.

Comment: Local should always be larger, the remote is requested first. But it may be a good idea to check for the difference to be in an interval instead of, good point.

Comment: Local is bigger if remote clock is ok. But this is exactly the fact to check.

Comment: Yes I realised that, hence I fixed it. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Getting a syntax error in expression for the `difference=$(awk -F '-' '{if ($1-$2 < 0) { print $2-$1 } else { print $1-$2} }' /tmp/.tmpdate)`

Comment: @PoldePaor Try now, I updated the script. It should calc the difference now and trim possible leading `-` symbols.

Comment: @ShellFish thanks the update now seems to be working as you've said

Comment: No problem, I will add some more explanation later so you can expand the script with little effort if you like.